# How to reverse acceptance in Android Device Manager?

Tags: geolocation, android-device-manager, location-services, google-location-history

If a user opens Android Device Manager in a browser (https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager), and selects an Android device that has never been accessed via Android Device Manager, they will be presented with the following screen:

[image: Android Device Manager opening screen]

If they select **"Accept"**, how do they later reverse that acceptance?

Answer (score 2):

Google has a weird mix of app settings, device settings, and a website to manage location permissions.  I've found that the easiest way to access most of it is through *Settings → Personal content* in the Google Maps app:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see I've gone through those one-by-one to disable all use of my location info by Google.  You might also need to go to https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols/location.

Android Device Manager still works though even though my device is not actively sending things up.  To remove your device from ADM entirely, you have to remove it from your Google account via https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity.  This will naturally also sign you out of Gmail and the like on your device.

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  I'll take a look at your recommendations.  It seems odd that the permission would be enabled via ADM, but then needs to be revoked via a different app.  But, usability is hardly Google's strong point.  Thanks again for you help.